# Getting dynamic dropdown value to a Session in PHP

Tags: php

a PHP newbie here and need to clarify a thing.

I have populated a dropdown box with data from a SQL database. The code looks like like below.

```
echo '<select id="dropMe" name="dropMe" style="width:150px; font-family:Georgia;">';
echo '<option value=""></option>';
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
{
    $value = $rec['route'];
    echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

What I want to know it is it possible to assign a value selected by a user to a SESSION hence this is a dynamic dropdown? (saveroute is my submit button)

```
if (isset($_POST['saveroute']))
{
    $Q = $_POST['dropMe'];
    $_SESSION['menuRoute'] = $Q;
    echo ($_SESSION['menuRoute']);
}
```

I code something like this, but I get an undefined error with 'dropMe'. I'm not quiet familier with this type of error and can some one throw some suggestions or point out any errors in the method.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Does the `$value` have any htmlentity characters?

Comment: check var_dump($_POST['dropMe']) and see what values it contains

Comment: @The DOCTOR from TARDIS No it doesn't !

Comment: that means you are not getting value in post?? is your select box is within form tag ?

Comment: @ Priyank Goswami actually there are two form tags. First form contains the dynamic dropdown content. A submit button on the second form calls in-order to display the selected option from the dropdown. I know its two different forms, thats why I thought I'd use a session. It is not a valid mechanism?

Comment: "saveroute" is it your submit button withing form 1 ? if is it so then your code should work

Comment: Nope! thats with form 2. How do I get it to work with form2?

Comment: hmmm thats the problem. merge your fileds in one form only. and then try

Comment: if (isset($_POST['saveroute']) AND isset($_POST['dropMe']))

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the whole POST array with

> print_r

Like this

```
print_r($_POST);
```

It looks like you are checking if "saveroute" is set and not "dropMe", looks like it doesn't exist.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to inspect the $_POST array to be sure that you are receiving the value you are expecting from the html form.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
print_r($_POST);
```

If that is correct then be sure that you have started the session before accesing it with:

```
session_start();
```